# How to find actual perimeter of printable area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to do is create an area on a page that users can interact with, which corresponds perfectly in size to the typical size of a piece of paper (A4), so that users are aware of exactly what the print will look like as they're constructing the printable area (before accessing print preview). I do not want to and should not have to use `@media print` at all.

It seems as if the perimeter of the printable area of the page corresponds to the actual browser window (`window.innerWidth`, etc) **only sometimes,** whereas at other times elements that are positioned **closer to the center of the page** are partially excluded from the printable area or even excluded altogether.

I can't seem to find any rhyme or reason to this. I've tried looking on SO and found one question in relation to printable areas but for a different language/context. Tried looking on Google. Nothing.

[edit] Now that I think about it, it's behaving kind of like viewport/viewbox cropping/zooming.

**Anybody know how would one go about finding the actual printable area of a webpage and or the perimeter thereof?**

## Example

An element with the position `right: 0` appears on the far right side of the page and will be included in the print, but ironically that very same element ends up becoming partially excluded when it is dragged **closer to the center** of the screen.

```
...
  <body>
    <div id="l"></div>
    <div id="r"></div>
    <textarea draggable="true" id="textarea"></textarea>
  </body>
...

@media print {
  #l, #r {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
  #l {
    background: blue;
  }
  #r {
    left: 50%;
    background: orange;
  }
  #textarea {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

[image]

## However, if I drag the image closer to the center of the page, ironically it becomes partially excluded from the printable area...

[image]

Comment: What is your definition of "printable area" because, an entire web page is printable.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds more determined by printer/paper size

Comment: @ScottMarcus by 'printable area' i mean all of the webpages's elements and parts thereof which are actually printed out are viewable in the print preview

Comment: @dimwittedanimal obvs lol but sometimes some elements are cut off are not printed at all because they fall outside of this area

Comment: It completely depends on what paper size, orientation,  and scale the user selects. Unfortunately, those are only chosen *after* the user has opened the print dialog, and by that time all the layout is set, so you can't really do anything about it.

Comment: Can you provide some images that showcase what you are describing?

Comment: @dimwittedanimal done and did

Answer (score 0):

Often times, a special style sheet that is designed solely for purposes of printing is associated with a web page. This style sheet can literally include/exclude anything.

Here's **[some reading](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)** on setting up a print style sheet.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, but that's not what this question is about. Even if an element is set to display using `@media print...` the *position* of that element on the page ultimately determines whether or not it is within the printable area and ultimately whether or not it will be printed.

Comment: @Anthony That's not true. If content is part of what's been included in the printed results, a printer will always print it. If it doesn't fit the paper, the printer will print a second sheet. This is the entire reason that print style sheets exist, because you can safely assume you have 8.5" x 11" to work with.

Comment: semantics. what i'm trying to do is make sure everything is on ONE page. i've edited my question. there's a better description as to what i'm trying to accomplish. i basically want the user to know what the printed page will look like before they choose to print it and as they're constructing/editing stuff in the printable zone of a single page

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. You need to form a complete answer or delete this altogether. I'm surprised you don't know that already.

Comment: @Anthony It's not semantics. I'm trying to tell you how to do exactly what you want, but you are arguing the point. Make a print style sheet and place a button on your page for "Print". Make the click of that button open a new window that has a document that is linked to the print style sheet in it. Then the user can print that or you can include `window.print()` in that document.

Comment: @Rob It's not a link only answer. You confuse a short answer with a link only one. And, I've been a member for many years.  I know what an answer should be.

Comment: Then where is your code that shows how to find the printable area of the screen? Or at least the method to do so?

Comment: @Rob So, you believe that all answers must contain code? Hmm. The OP isn't asking how to create/attach style sheets and so, providing that information in the answer wouldn't really be answering the question now would it?

Comment: It is semantics. But you're also wrong since it only detects a single page to print, even when elements are excluded from the print preview. Perhaps it prints more, but it only detects a single page to be printed

Comment: @Rob thank you <333333 [AT]Scott Marcus you're not answering MY question, THE question above...

Comment: @Anthony *But you're also wrong since it only detects a single page to print* You keep repeating this statement, which is incorrect. If you set up a print style sheet, you can use static units of measurement and the printed results will be as many pages as you dictate. But, you seem to want to argue instead of try it.

Comment: @Anthony That's entirely possible. Perhaps you should edit your question again to make it clearer?

Comment: i have edited my question. i don't want to be using `@media print` **at all**

Comment: my question might make more sense to you now that i've edited it an endless number of times lol